# SAS ODS output formatted weird

Tags: sas

I'm trying to export a content to Excel. I use the below code but my output excel formatting is horrible.

`ods excel file= "&cur_path/&project_name._Proc_Means.xlsx" style=printer ;
proc means data=&this_lib..&this_data;
run;
ods excel close;`

The output looks like

[image]

The huge blank gap makes the file unreadable. I also find out that it puts all the outputs in the same row instead of many different rows.

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have SAS 9.3+, which you must to use `ODS EXCEL`, you can add the [`stackodsoutput`](http://support.sas.com/kb/46/427.html) option to the `PROC MEANS` statement; that will give you a much more nicely formatted sheet.

```
ods excel file= "c:\temp\Proc_Means.xlsx" style=printer ;
proc means data=sashelp.cars stackodsoutput;
run;
ods excel close;
```

If you have prior to 9.3, you may want to use the `OUT=` option in `PROC MEANS` and then output the dataset yourself using `PROC EXPORT` or `PROC PRINT`.  The default `PROC MEANS` ODS output is not very table-friendly.